# Is there a way to calculate a dynamically sized widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to add a custom showMore widget if the skills widget which has a dynamic size(width) exceeds the screen width. On clicking the showMore widget it should show all the skills in a wrap .else show less.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to include the code you have already

Comment: Also, an alternative would be to wrap your widget in a `SingleChildScrollView()` hence, making it scrollable.

Comment: See the Wrap widget, which will fill and reflow your varying-sized chips.  You could put that into a scroll to get to other chips if it overflows the minimal space.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter

> Constraints go down and sizes go up

See [this documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).

Flutter uses a [single pass algorithm](https://medium.com/snapp-mobile/flutter-anatomy-layout-internals-part-1-de99b772ab99) to render your application. This is a technical choice to ensure performance but it comes with limitations.

One of them is that, when you are building the widget tree, you only have access to the constraints of the parent, and not any size of any widget (since they are not rendered yet).

### So a short answer to your question is:

No, you cannot do what you are trying to do (displaying something if some widgets are not fitting on the screen) since you don't have access to any sizes in the build method.

An alternative solution would be to use `Wrap` to wrap your chips or use a `ListView` on the horizontal axis to make the list of chips horizontally scrollable.

---

Anyway, if you really want to do this, you can hardcode the sizes of your chip and access the device size with `MediaQuery.of(context).size` or by using the `LayoutBuilder` and using `contraints.maxWidth` as the parent's width. Then you can check whether or not `numberOfChips * chipSize <= maxWidth`. But I wouldn't recommend it as the design wouldn't be responsive:

- All the chips will have the same size, so you'll end up with a big chip for "c" and maybe a long name like "python" won't fit in and you'll end up with overflow issues.
- What if the user changes the font size of his device? You will also end up with overflow issues.