# Flutter hide an overflowing widget

Tags: flutter, overflow

I have a row widget with variable width children which are conditionally visible, I sort the row items by priority. In case there isn't enough width to view all the items (small screen size), I want to hide items which will overflow (since they're of lesser priority by design).

eg:

```
   Container(
      width: 200, // screen size
      child: Row(
        children: [
          if (userCan1) Text("test"),
          if (userCan2) Icon(Icons.circle),
          if (userCan3) Container(width: 300),
          if (userCan4) Placeholder(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Here, for example, if Container width is 200, there is only enough space to view `Text("test")` and `Icon(Icons.circle)`, the rest of the children should be hidden.

I tried using layoutBuilder to get the available width for the row, but how can I know the width of all the children so I can calculate if they'll be visible or not?

Like text widget will use TextOverflow when there isn't enough space to render the whole text. How can I do the same for other widgets?

Using clippers will clip the overflowing parts, but I want to hide the whole overflowing widget.

Can you point me in the right direction? thank you.

Comment: If a scrollable widget solves your problem, try using 'Scrollbar' or 'SingleChildScrollView' widget

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I don't want scroll.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap each children widget with a sized box and given dynamic width using media Query and then check if the sum of those widgets correspond to width of container or not.

If not, then hide the last widget accordingly. You can add those widgets in a List to better programmatically mange insertions/deletions or use a flag to hide/show the widgets accordingly and mange the corresponding space by changing row alignment dynamically also.

```
List<Widgets> = [
SizedBox(
          width: widthA,
          child: WidgetA(),
        ),
         SizedBox(
          width: widthB,
          child: WidgetB(),
        ),
         SizedBox(
          width: widthC,
          child: WidgetC(),
         ),
];
on initstate

for loop ---> 
if(widthA+widthB+widthC > deviceWidth){
    listWidgets.remove(2);
}
.... other conditions such as widthA + width B and so on..

Container(
   width: deviceWidth,
   child: Row(
     children: listWidgets,
   ),
),
```

This is not a proper code but rough one to get a clarity on how we can hide the widgets depending on screen size. lemme know if you have any queries.

Update:- In case you don't know the width of the widgets,
refer [link] ([Is there a way to calculate a dynamically sized widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900315/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-a-dynamically-sized-widget))

Even if you are able to achieve this, it wouldn't be so feasible and responsive and there would be several parameters you need to take care of. Look for a different solution, i'll suggest.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the width for each child! For example, text widgets, I know I can use TextPainter here, but calculating the width for each child (with padding and margins) is a very dirty workaround.

Comment: Hey @Neut did you refer this answer [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900315/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-a-dynamically-sized-widget). Even if you are able to achieve this, it wouldn't be so feasible and responsive and there would be several parameters you need to take care of. Look for a different solution, i'll suggest.